# Lost data after running nodetool decommission

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have a 3 node cluster with 1 seed and nodes in different zones. All running in GCE with GoogleCLoudSnitch.

I wanted to change hardware on each node so I started with adding a new seed in a different region which joined perfectly to the cluster. Then I started with "nodetool decommission" and when done I removed the the node when it is down and "nodetool status" states it's not in the cluster. I did this for all nodes and lastly I did it on the "extra" seed in the different region just to remove it to get back to a 3 node cluster.

We lost data! What can possibly be the problem? I saw a commando, "nodetool rebuild", which I ran and actually got some data back. "nodetool cleanup" didn't help either. Should I have run "nodetool flush" prior to "decommission"?

At the time of running "decommission" most keyspaces had ..

```
{'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'europe-west1' : 2}"
```

Should I first altered key spaces to include the new region/datacenter, which would be "'europe-west3' : 1" since only one node exist in that datacenter? I also noted that some keyspaces in the cluster had by mistake ..

`{ 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 }`

Could this have caused the loss of data? It seems that it was in the "SimpleStrategy keyspaces" the data was lost.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I'm a ScyllaDB employee)

Did you 1st add new nodes to replace the ones you are decommissioning and configured the keyspace replication strategy accordingly? (you only mentioned the new seed node in your description, you did not mention if you did it for the other nodes).

Your data loss can very well be a result of the following:

- Not altering the keyspaces to include the new region/zone with the proper replication strategy and replication factor.
- Keyspaces that were configured with simple strategy (no netwrok aware) replication policy and replication factor 1. This means that the data was stored only in 1 node, and once that node went down and decommissioned, you basically lost the data.

Did you by any chance took snapshots and stored them outside your cluster? If you did you could try and restore them.

I would highly recommend reviewing these procedures for better understanding and the proper way to perform the procedure you intended to perform:

- http://docs.scylladb.com/procedures/add_dc_to_exist_dc/
- http://docs.scylladb.com/procedures/replace_running_node/

Comment: No, I did not add new nodes for the other, only for the seed, since a cluster needs at least one seed. But the new seed was in a different region, that maybe also was bad decision? I thought decommission should be enough or do I really need for every node to replace add a node before running decommission, isn't the tokens just streamed to the other two nodes?

Comment: I suppose the lost data is a result of bad keyspace config among other failures made by me. I will try your suggestions. I will make your answer as solving my issue if I can verify it.

Comment: @nicgul I think I did not fully understand the scenario you did.
1. You added a new node and replaced the seed node (BTW, this is the procedure: http://docs.scylladb.com/procedures/replace_seed_node/)
2. You started to decommission all the other nodes.
- Was it done one by one?
- You did not add new nodes instead, so where did you want to data to stream to if you eventually decommissned all you nodes?

Please clarify your steps...

Comment: Okay @TomerSan .. Sorry, I will try to be more clear. 1) Added one new node (a new seed node) in a different Google region. 2) Run node decommission on the first seed node. 3) Added new seed node with same ip as original in the original Google Region. 4) Run decommission on second node. 5) Added new node with same ip as second node. 6) Run decommission on third node. 7) Added new node with same ip as third node. 8) run decommission on the "extra" seed node residing in the different region. Thanks for taking me through this!

Comment: @nicgul, did you wait each time after adding a new node for the streaming to be completed, meaning it moves from UJ (Up Joining) to UN (Up Normal) state, before decommissioning other node?

Comment: I guess this is the thing I did not understand what "decommission" does, I need to add a node before decommission the other, right?   I only added a new node for the seed before decommission, not for the other ones. With the non.seed nodes I run decommission before before adding a new non-seed node. So the procedure should always be 1) Make sure all keyspaces have right replication factor according to cluster setup. 2) Add node and wait for "UN". 3) Run "decommission". This procedure should do the thing? What about nodetool rebuild and cleanup?

Comment: @TomerSan I'm curious: When you "decomission" a node, doesn't it divide its owned ranges (vnodes) to the other nodes? So even if a keyspace has RF=1, the vnodes owned by the to-be-decomissioned nodes will be sent to other nodes, and the data stream there, so no data would be lost?
If there's a case where "nodetool decomission" knows it will lose data, why isn't the operation aborted?

Comment: @nyh - you are correct. Even with RF=1 nodetool decommission should re-distribute the token ranges and stream/distribute the data (RF=1) to other remaining nodes.
You don't HAVE to add a node before decommissioning, but if you decommission all your nodes, you can potentially hit a situation where the remaining nodes won't have enough storage space to contain all the data. I was assuming did this in order to replace each node, as you originally wrote, and that's why I explained how to 1st add a new node (and wait for the UN state).

Comment: @nicgul - It could be that the seed alone being in a different region caused some problems, connectivity? firewall rules? open ports?

Can you describe your ring topology?
How many total nodes? how many are seeds?
Spread on how many regions?
How many nodes per region? 
How many seed nodes per region?